# Functions.php file

Tags: wordpress-theming

This is scripts. Php in which i enter all functions of the php which i have to included in functions file.. In this I add style and Javascript files..

```
  Function my_style() {
 Wp_enqueue_style('maincss', 'get_stylsheet_uri());
 Wp_enqueue_style('myscript', 
 'get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/myscript.js');}
```

This is functions. Php file in which i hookup all those   functions by adding action hooks and di action hooks..

```
  Include(get_template_directory(). 
   '/inc/Frontend/myscripts. Php') ;
  Add_action('Wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_style') ;
```

Plz tell me why its not working and its also not accepting my style. Css file. And then i add menus.. And also menus are not adding in websitee.. Also there is no error in compilation.

Comment: Well first try to write in lowercase. `Wp_enqueue_style` cannot be capitalized and you also have white space, for example, your `. Php` has space after the dot it and it should be `.php` in lowercase.

Comment: Sorry i  just write here in upper case as Wp but not in my coding.. I am new and i can't share images.. Otherwise u can see there is no issue and errors.. What to do 